# SMF Simple Machine Forum - Apply CSS style ONLY to the homepage

Tags: php, smf, simple-machines-forum

I would like to apply a CSS class to the  tag ONLY on the homepage on my SMF forum.

My problem is that I cannot seem to find any documented PHP code for SMF to detect the homepage, and only apply the CSS to that. Something like "if is home, echo class else nothing".

Is there any way to do this with SMF? or am I out of luck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could think of doing this is to detect the current URL, and then do:

```
if ($url == '/index.php') echo 'home';
```

Seems to work.

Not sure if there is a better way.